# How can I get the selected text from a dropdown list based using it’s index value?

Tags: jquery

how can I get the selected text from a dropdown list based using it’s index value?  Here’s what I’ve been working on for over three hours.  I’ve tried various versions of this code.

```
 $("#saveBtn").click(function () {
         var checked = [];
         var checkedindex = [];
         var theDate = [];
         var inputname = $("input[name='searchString']");
         $("input[name='selectedCourses']").each(function (i) {
             if (this.checked) {
                 checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
                 checkedindex.push(parseInt(i));

                 var thedate = $('inputname option:eq(i)').prop('selected', true);

                 alert(checkedindex + thedate.toString());
             }
         });



     });
```

Is it the way that I’m using this?

```
   $('inputname option:eq(i)').prop('selected', true);
```

Please help me with this one.  Thanks.

EDIT:

html:

```
    <select id="searchString" name="searchString">
    <option value="Day" selected="selected">Day</option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    </select>
```

I have a number of the same dropdownlists on the page with same id and name.

Comment: what's your HTML look like?

Comment: I've added the html to my original question.

Comment: _I have a number of the same dropdownlists on the page with same id and name._.....then it is invalid markup if same id used for multiple elements.

Comment: You'll need to share more of your HTML or (even better) make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I have a somewhat similar situation with my checkboxes.  The ids are different but the names are all the same.  I'm able to work with the checkboxes.  Since changing my ids won't work for me.  Is there another way to select an item based on it's index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same id for multiple elements is a issue and browser's stops the lookup when it gets the first id if you have multiple ids.

Yet i see **issues** in your code is this:

```
var inputname = $("input[name='searchString']");
```

In the above selector you have prefixed `input` while your element is `select` so that has to be:

```
var inputname = $("select[name='searchString']");
```

and here:

```
var thedate = $('inputname option:eq(i)').prop('selected', true);
//--------------^^^^^^^^^^---this is the selector variable and you have used 
//---------------------------as string and in ':eq(i)' i as a string
```

change to this:

```
var thedate = inputname.find('option:eq('+ i +')').prop('selected', true);
```

---

***how can I get the selected text***:

for getting the text:

```
var thedate = inputname.find('option:eq('+ i +')').prop('selected', true).text();
```

for getting the value:

```
var thedate = inputname.find('option:eq('+ i +')').prop('selected', true).val();
```

---

And you don't have to do this:

```
thedate.toString()
```

because `.text()` will give you a string.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation.  I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select item based on index then yous should concatenate you selector with that index:

```
$("select option:eq("+ i +")").prop('selected', true);
```

But what are you trying to achieve with that #saveBtn click handler?

You code so far has several problems:

1. You shouldn't have several elements on your page with same id.
2. There is no input with [name='selectedCourses'], so you need to use `$("select[name='selectedCourses']")`
3. `parseInt($(this).val())`. Why are you trying to parse int from string value?
4. `var thedate = $('inputname option:eq(i)').prop('selected', true); 
    alert(checkedindex + thedate.toString());`
     The `thedate` variable is jQuery object, so calling `.toString()` always will return `[object Object]`

If you are trying to get values of all selects on your page - you should use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function (it also works with checkboxes) like this:

```
$("select[name='selectedCourses']").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one.

```
 $("select").on("change",function(){
    alert($(this).val());
 });
```

you can try it here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/q5dYN/

Comment: I'm trying to get the ones that are already selected when I save the form.  Also "select" won't allow me to use the specific index of item.

Comment: use something like that on page load -- `$("select[name='selectedCourses']").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function then pass your variable, to get the text use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) try:

```
var thedate = $('#searchString option').eq(i);

thedate.prop('selected', true);

alert(thedate.text());
```